# How to stop chain execution for failing task in the middle of a chain?

Tags: python, task, celery, chain

**Question**

How to stop chain execution for a task that fails somewhere in the middle of a chain?

**Example**

```py
@app.task
def ok(i):
    print(f"ok = {i}")
    return i + 1


@app.task
def fail(i):
    print(f"fail = {i}")
    raise RuntimeError(str(i))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fails_in_the_middle = (ok.s(1) | fail.s() | ok.s())
    fails_in_the_end = (ok.s(1) | fail.s())

    for c in [fails_in_the_end, fails_in_the_middle]:
        resp = c.delay()
        try:
            resp.get(timeout=5)
        except RuntimeError:
            print("runtime error (as expected)")
        except celery.TimeoutError:
            # QUESTION: How do I make this never happen for `fails_in_the_middle`?
            print("timed out (not expected)")
```

**Observations**

- `fails_in_the_middle` chain: `resp.get(timeout=2)` always results in `TimeoutError`;
- `fails_in_the_end`: always raises `RuntimeError(2)` and doesn't wait for timeout.

It looks like `AsyncResult.get()` blocks forever if there are pending tasks in chain, but cleaning up the chain by setting `self.request.chain = None` does not help, the chain is still blocked until timeout is reached.

Behavior above is present when Redis is used both as a message broker and result storage. When tasks are marked as eager (executed within current process), the behavior is as expected.

Would be grateful for any insights. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a bug? Did you try to go through Celery issues?

Comment: Yeah, I'm exploring celery issues on github, there's a number of similar, yet not exactly the same issues. Most of issues I'm finding are related to error handlers not being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the [answer from celery-users group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/celery-users/gNib41XfJ_0/LVZF-BTZFwAJ), hopefully it will help someone else. All the credits go to Ing. Josue Balandrano Coronel.

> There's a caveat when getting the result the way you're doing it.
>   A chain is a bunch of tasks linked together, when you do `resp = c.delay()` you are queuing all the tasks in the chain
>
> The object that `c.delay()` returns is not a pointer to the entire chain but a pointer to the last task int he chain.
>   Meaning, `resp` ends up with a pointer to the result of the last task in the chain, in this case the second `ok.s()`.
>   This means that if the middle task fails and you try to do `resp.get()` it will timeout because the task that `resp` is pointing to never actually got executed.
>
> This also explains the behavior you're seeing for `fails_in_the_end` because `resp` is a pointer to `fail.s()` when you do `resp.get()` Celery will raise the error that happened in the task. This is how Celery handles accessing results of tasks which raised errors and there's no error handling in the task.
>
> Now, depending on what you actually want to do there's a few different options you can do. In order of recommendation.
>
> 1) You can add success and error handlers to the chain to make sure you're not working with an incomplete chain.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def success(self, result):
    print(f"Chain result: ${result}")
    print(f"Chain: ${self.chain}")

@app.task(bind=True)
def error(self, *args, **kwargs)
    print(f"args: ${args)")
    print(f"kwargs: ${kwargs}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fails_in_the_middle = (ok.s(1) | fail.s() | ok.s() | success.s()).on_error(error.s())
    fails_in_the_end = (ok.s(1) | fail.s() | success.s()).on_error(error.s())
```

> 2) Access chain results as a graph using `resp.collect(intermediate=True)`
>   `collect()` returns all the results in the chain as a directed acyclical graph (DAG). It's usually easier to transform this into a list so you can loop through each one of the results in order:

```
resp = c.delay()
for result in list(resp.collect(intermediate=True)):
    print(result.get())
```

> 3) Walk the chain graph backwards until you get to the parent and loop through the children to get the results.
>   Since what you end up with in `resp` is actually the last task in the chain you can walk the graph backwards until the first task in the chain and get the results from there:

```
resp = c.delay()
parent = resp.parent

while parent is not None:
    parent = resp.parent

for child in parent.children:
    child.get()
```

Comment: None of these solutions seem to work for me to detect a fail in the middle? The result.get() just hangs forever in the intermediate collect loop.  As does a while results.ready(): loop.  Any chance you can share a full working example, including how you are actually getting the failure result back?

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem.  It's because I was using the rpc:// celery backend, it seems very buggy with these chains.  I switched to amqp:// and it works perfect now.